# Laravel login redirect issue based on role of user: redirect too many times

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

I am trying to make code in Laravel using middleware which will redirect user depending on user's role. The issue is I get error: redirected too many times whether user is simple user or admin. I am so far performing check whether user is admin by providing string in middleware, i am not accessing db yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code below:

**mid.php** (Middleware)

```
class mid
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->session()->has('user')){
            $user = $request->session()->get('user');
            if($user == "pujan@pujanovic.com"){
                return redirect()->route('adminview');      
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('userview');      
            }
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('poruka','Niste administrator!');
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get("/","HomeController@index")->name('index');
Route::get("/login","HomeController@loginview")->name('login');
Route::get("/admin","HomeController@adminview")->name('adminview')->middleware('mid');


Route::post("/login","LoginController@login");

Route::get("/user","HomeController@userview")->name('userview')->middleware('mid');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use App\Models\UserModel;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    //
    
    public function login(Request $request){
        $email=$request->input('email');
        $password=$request->input('password');

        $this->validate($request,[
        'email'=>'required',
        'password'=>'required'
        ]);
        
        $pass=md5($password);
        $data=DB::SELECT("SELECT * FROM users where email=? and password=?",[$email,$password]);
        
        if (count($data)){
            session()->put('user',$email);
            $value=session('user');
        
        return redirect()->route('userview');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('success','wrong data');
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware will redirect a user who isn't `"pujan@pujanovic.com"` to the `userview` route. You have this middleware assigned to the `userview` route.

So if there is a user in the session and they are not `"pujan@pujanovic.com"` they will get into an endless loop being redirected to the same route, then the middleware will redirect them to the same route again, in a loop.

This is also an issue for when you have this assigned to the `adminview`. If you are the "admin" and you try to hit that route, you will **also** end up in an endless loop.

In short you are telling it to redirect endlessly.

This middleware will never let anyone get to the destination route. It can only redirect to somewhere else.

**Update:**

Here is a rough idea of what you could do for an Admin check middleware

Admin Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, $next)
{
    // an auth middleware could handle this itself
    if (! ($email = $request->session()->get('user'))) {
        // not logged in at all
        return redirect()->route('login');
    } 

    if ($email != 'admin@email.com') {
        // not the admin user
        // redirect them away
        return redirect()->route(...);
    }

    // let the request pass through as we have determined they are the admin
    return $next($request);
}
```

This middleware would get assigned to a route that you only want the admin to be able to access.

Comment: So how can i fix it?

Comment: not even sure what you are actually trying to do with that middleware ... if you check the last paragraph of my answer: this middleware never lets anyone pass through, it can only redirect, the way it is setup .. so not sure what you are doing

Comment: Well i am trying to redirect user on certain view depending is he admin or user. Which code changes i need to apply then specificly?

Comment: i really can't tell you because I can't fully make sense of what you are trying to accomplish ... seems you are trying to make a single middleware do too many things and in the end it can't do anything basically

Comment: So i need two middlewares?

Comment: i added an example of what one of the middleware could look like

Comment: I have applied your code exactly and still get same error..

Comment: you can't apply this middleware to the same route that you would be redirecting to in the middleware

Comment: To which routes exactly should i apply this middleware? It seems to be working i am just not sure which routes should have it.

Comment: this middleware will redirect away anyone who isn't the admin ... so any route that you **only** want the admin to be able to access would have this middleware

Comment: I need this middleware to redirect anyone who isn't logged in to the login page and those who are logged in to determine whether they can access admin view or not.

Comment: alright good luck ... that is exactly what this middleware i have above does